# How to tell activity that fragments are finished with network calls

Tags: android, android-fragments, retrofit

I have this situation:

1. I got main activity that user will open when he start an app an inside that activity is a Viewpager alongside tabs in top bar so user can navigate between 4 fragments.
2. Every fragment is using retrofit to do some network request like load news data, load about section etc.

I am adding fragments to pager in classic way:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new WelcomeFragment(), "Home");
        adapter.addFrag(new NewsFragment(), "News");
        adapter.addFrag(new AboutFragment(), "About");
        adapter.addFrag(new Locators(), "Locations");


        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Network calls in fragments are done by Retrofit(Example call bellow:)

```
NetworkSDK.getInstance().getNews(size, offset, new Callback<List<News>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<News>> call, Response<List<News>> response) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<News>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Now i want to implement some kind of progressbar (loader) that will spin on main activity until all 4 fragments are finished with network calls. How can i notify main activity that fragments network calls are finished ? I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For communicating from a Fragment up to its Activity, you can define an interface in the Fragment class and implement it within the Activity. The Fragment captures the interface implementation during its onAttach() lifecycle method and can then call the Interface methods in order to communicate with the Activity. You can communicate to the activity using interfaces. [Check Communicate from Fragment to Activity official documentation.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#DefineInterface).

The first brute force solution that comes to mind is that you can have 4 booleans in the Activity. Using interfaces communicate to the Activity. When each of them receives the data, set the corresponding bool to be true. Then when all 4 are set to true, close the dialog. Following code sniplet might give a better idea of what I'm trying to convey.

```
bool a,b,c,d;

public void setA(bool success) {
    a = true;
    closeDialogIfPossible();
}

public void setB(bool success) {
    b = true;
    closeDialogIfPossible();
}

... 

public void closeDialogIfPossible() {
    if (a && b && c && d) {
        // Close dialog here.
    }
}
```